# Index out of bounds when using element.all(by.binding)

Tags: protractor

**User flow:** Search for a case >> Search for an item within that case >> expect returned number of results matches value

```
describe('Search', function () {

  beforeEach(function () {
    loginPage.signIn();
    loginPage.login(username, password);
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    homePage.logOut();
  });

  it('alecxes suggestion code', function () {
    var presenceOfAll = function(elementArrayFinder) {
      return elementArrayFinder.count().then(function (count) {
        return count > 0;
      });
    };

    homePage.searchForCase(test_case);
    filterSearchMenu.searchWithinCase(search_argument);
    var hits = element.all(by.binding('response.hits.total'));
    browser.wait(presenceOfAll(hits), TIMEOUT);

    expect(element.all(by.binding('response.hits.total')).count()).toEqual(4);
  });
});
```

This **fails** with **expected 4 but was 0**

```
describe('Search', function () {

  searchResultTotal = element(by.binding('response.hits.total'));

  beforeEach(function () {
    loginPage.signIn();
    loginPage.login(username, password);
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    homePage.logOut();
  });

  it('should be able to search', function () {
    homePage.searchForCase(test_case);
    filterSearchMenu.searchWithinCase(search_argument);
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(searchResultTotal), TIMEOUT).then(function () {
      expect(element.all(by.binding('response.hits.total')).count()).toEqual(4);
    });
  });
});
```

This **works** but comes back with a **warning that more then one element found for locator by.binding('response.hits.total')**.

```
describe('Search', function () {

  beforeEach(function () {
    loginPage.signIn();
    loginPage.login(username, password);
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    homePage.logOut();
  });

  it('should be able to search', function () {
    homePage.searchForCase(test_case);
    filterSearchMenu.searchWithinCase(search_argument);
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element.all(by.binding('response.hits.total')).first()), TIMEOUT).then(function () {
      expect(element.all(by.binding('response.hits.total')).count()).toEqual(4);
    });
  });
});
```

This **Fails and throws an index out of bounds**.

Second set of eyes and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve it with a *custom Expected Condition* that would check if there are more than 0 elements matching a locator found:

```
var presenceOfAll = function(elementArrayFinder) {
  return elementArrayFinder.count().then(function (count) {
    return count > 0;
  });
};

var hits = element.all(by.binding('response.hits.total'));
browser.wait(presenceOfAll(hits), TIMEOUT);

expect(element.all(by.binding('response.hits.total')).count()).toEqual(4);
```

Comment: I went ahead and put this presenceOfAll function inside the spec: `it('should be able to search', function () {
    homePage.searchForCase('KJ_000269_1');
    filterSearchMenu.searchWithinCase('Serum');
    var searchResult = element.all(by.binding('response.hits.total'));
    browser.wait(presenceOfAll(searchResult), TIMEOUT);
    searchResult.then(function (results) {
      expect(results.length).toBe(4);
    });
  });` and it fails with "Expected 0 to be 4.". I don't get why this stuff isn't waiting. Very frustrating.

Comment: Sorry was updating my comment :) Had a lot to say and wanted to make sure it was clear. The formatting of the code is odd, If I need to post it another comment to be more clear let me know.

Comment: @Sevfuria okay :) Not sure how is that possible though. The wait ensures that there will be at least 1 element found. What if you do `expect(searchResult.count()).toEqual(4)` right after the wait? Thanks.

Comment: Adding the expect right after the wait fails with "Expected 0 to be 4." still. When I add a `browser.sleep(1000)` right before the browser.wait it passes. Makes no sense.

Comment: @Sevfuria what if you "refind" the elements after the wait, like in the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Added the 'refind' code from the answer and it still fails with the "Expected 0 to be 4". Again adding a 1 second sleep right before the expect and it works.

Comment: When logging count in presenceOfAll count is 0. Is return count > 0; correct? Should it be some sort of if condition? I'm fairly new to JavaScript.

Comment: If count is always logged as 0, then Idk why aren't u getting a Timeout Exception?..that's what is weird in this case.

Comment: I agree. I honestly don't know where to go with this issue now. For right now I am just finding the element(by.binding) and accepting the fact that it will throw an error. I don't know what else to do. Thanks for your help @alecxe

Comment: @Sevfuria Okay. Could you post the complete code you have so far (probably better create a gist or edit the question) and the current output? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the working/warning code and the failing code in my original question. Let me know if anything needs explaining or you need any additional code.

Comment: I also added the code for the index out of bounds error.

Comment: @Sevfuria thanks, but why are u using 'then()' on the 'browser.wait()'? What happens if u put the expectation after the wait? Thanks

Comment: maybe it is my lack of understanding of then() but I essentially wanted to have the expect() happen right after the wait explicitly. Isn't that what the then() is used for? Promises? Maybe I am using it wrong but I thought the wait returned a promise? Either way I tried it without calling then() and the test passes still.

Comment: For some reason I was under the impression I needed to use then(). I understand there is a control flow that Protractor uses but I am not entirely sure why I decided to use then(). I believe I have seen some issues with Protractor not waiting for things to resolve and therefor thought I needed to use then(). I should try and avoid using then()?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking `visibilityOf` doesn't like multiple elements. Try:

```
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element.all(by.binding('response.hits.total')).first()), TIMEOUT);
```

Comment: Cant call `.first()` off of a single element if I remember correctly, but I tried it and it gave me the expected **error element(...).first is not a function**. Needs to be off of a `element.all` but Expected Conditions doesn't like that. When I try to do `browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element.all(by.binding('response.hits.total')).first()), TIMEOUT);` it still gives me a **Index out of bounds.**

Comment: Also just wanted to add a note that currently in one of my page objects I am calling `.first()` off of an `element.all`. `this.riskTypes = element.all(by.css('rga-filters > rga-risk-facet > div > md-checkbox'));` and it is being used like `browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(this.riskTypes.last()), TIMEOUT);`. The only difference is that it is finding an element by css. Not sure if it is the binding that is throwing it off or not.

Comment: woops... sorry. I meant `element.all`. Yeah, binding might be the issue? Seems like this should work.

Comment: I would think but for some reason it isn't. Not sure if it is a bug or I am doing it wrong. I am going to try alecxe's suggestion. Ill report back with my findings, but I do agree my original way "should" work.